# Retrieve data from multidimensional JSON array in React JS

Tags: reactjs, arrays, json, dictionary, key

How do i retrieve the value in multidimensional array in React JS..?Tell me the answer

```
"result": {
"task": "Hello",
"data": [
  {
    "title": "Sample data one",
    "subtitle": "Sample subtitle data one",
    "amount": 100
  },
     {
    "title": "Sample data two",
    "subtitle": "Sample subtitle data two",
    "amount": 200
  },
      {
    "title": "Sample data three",
    "subtitle": "Sample subtitle data three",
    "amount": 300
  }
]
```

}

Comment: To get a list of tiltes
array.result.data.map( item => item.title)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like

```
array.result.data[0].title
```

Comment: I recommend against using rhetoric questions in answers. It risks being misunderstood as a question instead of an answer. Even if you have trouble finding the "?" on your keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

```
{data.map?.((element,i)=>{
  <div key={i}>                                                      
   <h1>{element.title}<h1/> `map`                                         
   <h1>{element.subtitle}<h1/>`map`                         
   <h1>{element.amount}<h1/>`ma`                                 
 <div/>
})}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.